# Dodge Stratus struggling to accelerate

Tags: dodge, stratus

I have a '97 Dodge Stratus, 4cylinder 2.0L that I purchased nearly a year and a half ago. It has approximately 140,000 miles on it.

It struggles to accelerate properly at certain speeds. The sound resembles  "spitting & sputtering", and feels as if it's going to shut off, (but hasn't yet). With light bucking at times, I will hear something like air being released quickly out of a compressor. It sounds as if it is coming from the engine on the drivers side. The check engine light just came on. What would you suggest?

Comment: Welcome to the site. [We need some direction](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1473/675). Please provide us with the trouble codes so that we can help you.

Comment: Your car is OBD2 compatible. Go and get the trouble codes read with any generic scanner. If you are in the USA you can go to an autozone and they will do it for free. I have dealt with this specific car before on a similar issue. Having the trouble codes will help. You can also pull the trouble codes yourself by following the procedure explained here: http://www.troublecodes.net/chrysler/

Comment: Thank you... There's an Auto Zone under 5mins away from me, I will have them read it.. Again, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No worries. Make sure to update the main question with the details when you have them. :)